# Why do I get many SSE request that slow down my webpage in my NUXT.js project?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, eventsource

I have a project implemented using NUXT.js (ssr mode). Every time I refresh pages, I got three or four sse requests (like **_loading/sse**) in the network console. Those sse requests are slow and would fail in the end and they cause page loading time slow in my computer (I run whole project in local computer).
Anyone knows what those sse requests are and how to get rid of them?

Comment: the only place in my project where I can find _loading/sse is in .nuxt/components/nuxt-build-indicator.vue file, which is generated by NUXT.js itself.

Answer (score 0):

What you refer to is a [loading-screen](https://github.com/nuxt/loading-screen/blob/master/app/app.vue) and looks like there must be something in your app which si firing many requests and takes quite a while to render or fail.

You need to check through your app code what generates those requests and where they might fail.

Comment: he only place in my project where I can find _loading/sse is in .nuxt/components/nuxt-build-indicator.vue file, which is generated by NUXT.js itself. The code is this.sse = new EventSource('/_loading/sse')
      this.sse.addEventListener('message', event => this.onSseMessage(event))

Comment: 'loading-screen' module is internally being used by nuxt.js to show loading screen and this screen is being displayed to while resources are being built. This suggests that your local build is somehow failing. What is the console output you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

For future readers:

In my case this happened when I tried to add metadata in head, on nuxt.config.js

on the compiled head of the page there are some:
`data-n-head="ssr"`